# Transform a column in a sparksql dataframe using python

Tags: apache-spark, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I have a spark sql dataframe with a whole bunch of columns. One of the columns ("date") is a date field. I want to apply the following transformation to every row in that column.

This is what would I do if it were a pandas dataframe. I cant seem to figure out the spark equivalent

```py
df["date"] = df["date"].map(lambda x: x.isoformat() + "Z")
```

The column has values of the form
2020-12-07 01:01:48

I want the values to be of the form:
2020-12-07T01:01:48Z

Comment: Try .withColumn

Comment: Please share an example of your data frame so people can reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, DateType, StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

schema = StructType([
     StructField("date",StringType(),True),
     StructField("age", StringType(),True)])


df = spark.createDataFrame([(None,22),(None,25)],schema=schema)

Z = F.lit("Z").cast(StringType())
datetime = F.current_date().cast(StringType())

datetimeZ = F.concat(datetime,Z)

df = df.withColumn("date", datetimeZ)

df.show(5)

+-----------+---+
|       date|age|
+-----------+---+
|2021-06-15Z| 22|
|2021-06-15Z| 25|
+-----------+---+
```